# Set background color in LibreOffice base form

Tags: forms, libreoffice-base

The title pretty much says it all.  I am trying to create a form in design view in LibreOffice and I can't see any control that allows me to set the background color. I've seen some old answers to this on the internet but the images they show and the buttons they mention apparently have nothing to do with the LibreOffice I am working with.  I'm on a Mac, BTW, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the form for editing.  Then go to *Format -> Page -> Area* and choose a background color.

[image: page background color]